# Matlab: create this particular SPARSE matrix to solve a quadratic program

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I am trying to solve the following large scale quadratic program:

> min (1/2*x'*Q*x + c'*x) subject to x >= 0

where the vector `x` is of dimension `(n*d^2)` where `n` is very large and `d` is small (in my problem: `n = 220512` and `d = 16`).

The matrix `Q` is sparse, and is constructed as follows.

```
one = ones(d,1);
A = kron(eye(d),one');
B = repmat(diag(one),1,d);
M = A'*A + B'*B;
```

and `Q` is a **block diagonal** matrix where there are `n` identical blocks (in the diagonal), each block is the matrix `M`.

Now I would like to create `Q` as a sparse matrix (otherwise there will be a MEMORY problem when solving the original quadratic program, using `quadprog` for example).

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Please only use relevant tags and read their description before using them.

Comment: @Ali: excuse-me for the annoyance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this answer from someone:

```
MSparse = sparse(M);
% replicate: please don't test with n=220512 directly
Mblk = repmat({MSparse}, 1, n);
% convert do block diagonal
Q = blkdiag(Mblk{:});
```

The matrix is created and stored after about 15 minutes.

However, the matrix takes ~9GB of memory and thus slows down everything (although it takes only 1.1Gb when saved to file), so I guess there is no much hope to solve the original quadratic problem using *quadprog* (an example is given [here](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/optim/ug/large-sparse-quadratic-program-with-interior-point-algorithm.html)).

Answer (score 0):

To build `Q` in the sparse "domain", the easiest way is to loop over blocks:

```
one = ones(d,1);
A = kron(eye(d),one');
B = repmat(diag(one),1,d);
M = A'*A + B'*B;

S = d^2*n;
Q = sparse(S, S); %'// preallocates with zeros
for b = 0:d^2:S-1
    Q(b+(1:d^2),b+(1:d^2)) = M;
end
```

Example result for `d=2` and `n=3`:

```
>> full(Q)
ans =
     2     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     2     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     2     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     2     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     2     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     2     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     1     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     2     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     2     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No problem on small sizes but for my problem it's been run for minutes and still keep running... :(

Comment: It's been 25 minutes now, no news :( The specs of my computer are not so bad: 16GB RAM, Intel Core i7-4770 3.4 GHz (quadcore).